# Flutter - Character encoding is not behaving as expected

Tags: flutter, dart, character-encoding, special-characters

I am parsing a local `JSON` file that has words containing **rarely used special characters** in Icelandic.

When displaying the characters I get mixed up symbols but not the characters, for some others I just get a square instead of a symbol.

I am using this type of encoding `"\u00c3"`

**Update:** Example of the characters I am using: þ, æ, ý, ð

**Q:** What is the best way to display those kind of characters and avoid any chance of display failures?

**Update #2:**
How I am parsing:

```
Future<Null> getAll() async{
    var response = await 
    DefaultAssetBundle.of(context).loadString('assets/json/dictionary.json');
    var decodedData = json.decode(response);
    setState(() {
      for(Map word in decodedData){
        mWordsList.add(Words.fromJson(word));
      }
    });
  }
```

The class:

```
class Words{
  final int id;
  final String wordEn, wordIsl;

  Words({this.id, this.wordEn, this.wordIsl});

  factory Words.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json){
    return new Words(
      id: json['wordId'],
      wordEn: json['englishWord'],
      wordIsl: json['icelandicWord']
    );
  }
}
```

JSON Model:

```
{
    "wordId": 47,
    "englishWord": "Age",
    //Here's a String that has two special characters
    "icelandicWord": "\u00c3\u00a6vi"
}
```

Comment: can you show that special character?

Comment: @dubace check the update!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that your JSON is stored locally.

Let's say you have
`Map<String, String> jsonObject = {"info": "Æ æ æ Ö ö ö"};`

So to show your text correctly you have to encode and decode back your JSON with utf-8.

I understand that's serialization and deserialization are costly operations, but's it's a workaround for locally stored JSON objects that contains UTF-8 texts.

```
import 'dart:convert';
jsonDecode(jsonEncode(jsonObject))["info"]
```

If you get that JSON from server, then it's much more simpler, for example in `dio` package you can chose `contentType` params that's is "application/json; charset=utf-8" by default.

Comment: I think I am a bit lost here, can you provide a little more help?! my json object is like so : `{
        "wordId": 1,
        "englishWord": "example",
        "icelandicWord": "Æ æ æ Ö ö ö"
    }`  and in my .dart file I am parsing the json like this: `child: FutureBuilder(
        future: DefaultAssetBundle.of(context).loadString('assets/json/dictionary.json'),
        builder: (context, snapshot){
          var decodedData = json.decode(snapshot.data.toString());`

Comment: try to create your JSON this way: `decodedData = jsonDecode(snapshot.data.toString())`

Comment: it didn't work, but if this helps, I got the icelandic words like this in the json : `s\u00c3\u00a6kja` the encoding is concatinated with the rest of the string (if that makes any sense)

Comment: What about `jsonDecode(jsonEncode(decodedData))["icelandicWord"]` ?
It's ugly I know, but for me that helped. Try if it works for you

Comment: I keep getting `Another exception was thrown: type 'String' is not a subtype of type 'int' of 'index'`

Comment: Can you show some compilable widget where you are doing it?

Comment: I added more details, hope you can find time to check it and help you better understand my situation!

Answer (score 20):

I had similar issues with accented characters. They were not displayed as expected. 
This worked for me

```
final codeUnits = source.codeUnits;
return Utf8Decoder().convert(codeUnits);
```

Comment: Just to clarify for future readers, this works and the code must be invoked on the response body, BEFORE the jsonDecode. So ```codeUnits = response.body.codeUnits```

Comment: Another tiny tip: if you know the json value is string, you can do like, `response["id"].toString().codeUnits`

Comment: Worked like a charm.  Thanks!

Comment: This should be the best answer!! It works!!